# Inserting random number into table with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table that I would like to insert 2 random numbers into.  The table creates fine but I am getting an error inserting the numbers.

```
<?php
$host = 'host';
$user   = 'user';
$password   = 'pass';
$database   = 'data';


$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

// check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$db->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS POINTS');

$r1 = (rand(1,20));
$r2 = (rand(1,20));

$sql = "CREATE TABLE points (X INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Y INT(2))";
$db->query($sql);

$result  = $db->query("INSERT INTO points((X,Y) VALUES ($r1, $r2))");
if (!$result){
  echo "error in inserting record.";
  exit(1);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your INSERT line should be:

```
 $result  = $db->query("INSERT INTO points (X,Y) VALUES ($r1, $r2)");
```

You have extra parenthesis that causes the error.

Comment: No problem Brad, pay more attention next time.

Comment: Please tick this answer if you have time. Thanks!